# How to derive the Bethe stopping power formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I need the derivation of Bethe formula for stopping power, but I can't see the corresponding paper to this matter.

> Application of Ordinary Space-Time Concepts in Collision Problems and Relation of Classical Theory to Born's Approximation. E. J. Williams. [*Rev. Mod. Phys.* **17** no. 2-3 (1945) pp. 217-226](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.17.217).

Can anyone help me about this paper please?

Comment: you cannot open the link? because it opens for me..

Comment: Did it ask you for \$35.00?

Comment: yes but i found it. there are better reference for this matter.